# Determining sides of a quadrilateral from 3d position vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

We are given 4 position vectors

$$ p_1 = (1,3,-1), p_2 = (2,4,-1), p_3 = (0,-2,3),p_4 = (2,-4,1) $$

So i found that all 4 position vectors lie in the same plane P. But after that we are told to find the area of the quadrilateral that the 4 points describe. I have attempted to describe the quadrilateral as 2 triangles and then solve for those areas. However how would you determine which distance vectors would determine the side lengths and not give the diagonals of the quadrilateral? Or should i think of this problem a different way and not solve for 2 triangles?

Comment: Consider the affine vectors formed by the differences of the points in questions. Just make sure to pick _the correct points_ to form the affine vectors. Then take the norm of the cross product of such vectors. That quantity will be the area you're looking for. I can expand this into an answer if there's something you feel isn't quite right.

Comment: @IgnacioRojas Sorry but can you clarify what affine vectors are since I havent heard the term from our lectures. And can you clarify what you mean by correct points aswell as that was my confusion aswell with trying to make 2 separate triangles.

Comment: An affine vector is a translation of a vector from the origin to another point in space. For example $\vec{p_1p_2}=(2,4,-1)-(1,3,-1)=(1,1,3)$ is the affine vector which goes from the endpoint of $p_1$ to the endpoint of $p_2$. When picking the correct points, I mean that you shouldn't take $\vec{p_1p_2}$ and $\vec{p_3p_1}$ for example, because the orientation of those vectors might be reversed. I think @Nathalie has detailed the answer quite well! If you wish me to clarify more, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the four points be $A,B,C,D$ which are known to lie in a single plane.

Take the vector differences

$ V_1 = B - A $

$ V_2 = C - A $

$ V_3 = D - A $

Compute $ V_1 \times V_2 $ and $ V_2 \times V_3 $.  These should point in **the same direction**.  Then the area is

$ \text{Area} = \dfrac{1}{2} \bigg( \| V_1 \times V_2 \| + \| V_2 \times V_3 \| \bigg) $

And the sides are $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $DA$.

If they point in opposite directions, then **switch** $C$ and $D$, and repeat the calculation of $V_1 \times V_2$ and $V_2 \times V_3$.  If the cross products point in the same direction, then apply the above calculation of the area.

If they still point in opposite directions, then $V_1$ is in between $V_2$ and $V_3$.  In this case, switch $B$ and $C$, and repeat the calculation of $V_1 \times V_2$ and $V_2 \times V_3$.  Now they will point in the same direction, and the above calculation of area applies.

As an explicit example, taking the following points,
p = A + t (1, 2, 1) + s (3, 2, 0)
$A = (1, 3, -1), B = (2,5,0), C = (-2,1,-1) , D = (9, 11, 1) $

$V_1 = B - A = (1, 2, 1), V_2 = C - A = (-3, -2, 0), V_3 = D - A = (8, 8, 2) $

$V_1 \times V_2 = (1, 2, 1) \times (-3, -2, 0) = (2, -3, 4) $

$V_2 \times V_3 = (-3, -2, 0) \times (8, 8, 2) = (-4, 6, -8) $

Since they point in opposite directions, we'll switch $C$ and $D$, so that now

$A = (1, 3, -1), B = (2,5,0), D = (-2,1,-1) , C = (9, 11, 1) $

$V_1 = B - A = (1, 2, 1), V_3 = D - A = (-3, -2, 0), V_2 = C - A = (8, 8, 2) $

$V_1 \times V_2 = (1, 2, 1) \times (8,8, 2) = (-4, 6, -8) $

$V_2 \times V_3 = (8, 8, 2) \times (-3, -2, 0) = (4, -6, 8) $

Since they still point in opposite directions, we'll make the last switch, which is, we'll switch $B$ and $C$, so that now we have

$A = (1, 3, -1), C = (2,5,0), D = (-2,1,-1) , B = (9, 11, 1) $

$V_1 = B - A = (8, 8, 2), V_2 = C - A = (1, 2, 1), V_3 = D - A = (-3, -2, 0)

$V_1 \times V_2 = (8, 8, 2) \times (1,2, 1) = (4, -6, 8) $

$V_2 \times V_3 = (1,2,1) \times (-3, -2, 0) = (2, -3, 4 ) $

Now these point in the same direction.  So the ordered vertices of the quadrilateral are the final onces in this order $ABCD$ and the area is

$ \text{Area} = \dfrac{1}{2} \bigg( \sqrt{ 4^2 + 6^2 + 8^2 } + \sqrt{2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 } \bigg) = \dfrac{3}{2} \sqrt{29} $